# Get and count node neighbors Python

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, nodes, networkx

I am trying to read a file with node pairs and weight. I have find the neighbours of each pair individual and combined both also count them. Later find the ratio of the neighbours that each node has. I am stuck with finding nodes.

infile.txt

```
0_node1 0_node2 0w
1_node1 1_node2 1w
2_node1 2_node2 2w
3_node1 3_node2 3w
4_node1 4_node2 4w
```

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G = nx.read_edgelist('infile.txt', data=[("weight", float)])

def get_triangle(G):
  for n1 in G.nodes:
    neighbors1 = set(G[n1])
    for n2 in filter(lambda x: x>n1, nodes):
      neighbors2 = set(G[n2])
      common = neighbors1 & neighbors2
      for n3 in filter(lambda x: x>n2, common):
         print n1
         print n2
         print n3
```

I did check the indentations in program does not seem to be problem. I not getting the neighbours list.

Comment: There aren't any triangles in your input graph ([shown here](http://cl.ly/image/3g100B42222d)), so your function won't output them. Also, I'm not sure what your `filter` expressions are supposed to do...

Comment: @mdml That is just a sample data. I have to find individual and combined neighbours of both nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do anything with the values I suggest yield'ing a 3 node tuple.

I had to change the data so the import would work (i stripped out the w's) and there is support for finding triangle nodes in networkx which helps limit how many objects we are iterating over each time.

infile.txt

```
0_node1 0_node2 0
1_node1 1_node2 1
2_node1 2_node2 2
3_node1 3_node2 3
4_node1 4_node2 4
0_node1 1_node2 5
0_node2 1_node2 6
0_node2 1_node1 7
```

[image]

code:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools as it

def get_triangles(G):

    def found_rotation(x):
        for rotation in it.permutations(x):
            if rotation in triangles_duplicates:
                return 1
                return 0

    triangles = []
    triangles_duplicates=[]
    triangle_nodes = dict((x,nx.triangles(G,x))  for x in G.nodes() if nx.triangles(G,x) > 0)

    for vertex1  in triangle_nodes:
        vertex1_neighbors_that_are_triangles = set(G.neighbors(vertex1)).intersection( \
                                                                                       set(triangle_nodes) )
        for vertex2 in vertex1_neighbors_that_are_triangles:
            if triangle_nodes[vertex2] > 0:
                vertex2_neighbors_that_are_triangles_and_not_vertex1 = \
                                                                       set(G.neighbors(vertex2)).intersection(\
                                                                                                              G.neighbors(vertex1))-{vertex1}-{vertex2}
                for vertex3 in vertex2_neighbors_that_are_triangles_and_not_vertex1:
                    if triangle_nodes[vertex3]>0:
                        for z in G.neighbors(vertex3):
                            if (vertex1 == z) and  not found_rotation((vertex1,vertex2,vertex3)):
                                triangle_nodes[vertex1] -=1
                                triangle_nodes[vertex2] -=1
                                triangle_nodes[vertex3] -=1
                                triangles.append((vertex1,vertex2,vertex3))
                                triangles_duplicates.append((vertex1,vertex2,vertex3))
    return triangles

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #G = nx.karate_club_graph()
    G = nx.read_edgelist('this.txt', data=[("weight",int)])
```

With data like this the answer would be 2 triangles
(or you could switch it with karate_club_graph and get 45)

I'd be interested in seeing improvements if you do something with this.

Comment: Thanks for the program. Actually i am trying to implement topological overlap of network data with weight. Any suggestions in that direction .

Comment: I re-read your question and I'm wondering what "ratio of the neighbors" you are talking about and could you point me to a tutorial on topological overlap?

Comment: http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/88/18/04/PDF/p327-vazdemelo.pdf Section 5.1.2. Topological Overlap. I also have to consider the weight in my case. The above reference they do not consider the weight.